# Adafruit nrf52840 loops program

Tags: python, ipad, keyboard, hid, adafruit

I'm using Adafruit "BLE HID Keyboard Buttons" tutorial : I wanted to use arrows in order to navigate in the window with accessibility->access control on an iPad but as soon as I get connected to bluetooth, the characters defined for the five buttons display in a repetitive sequence in any text field I open (browser, note app ...etc.). How can I stop this repetitive sequence in order to use the five buttons only when I press on any of the five buttons? I didn't see any loop in the script (I just fiddle with programming)

```
#This example acts as a BLE HID keyboard to peer devices.
#Attach five buttons with pullup resistors to Feather nRF52840
#each button will send a configurable keycode to mobile device or computer

  import time
  import board
  from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction

  import adafruit_ble
  from adafruit_ble.advertising import Advertisement
  from adafruit_ble.advertising.standard import ProvideServicesAdvertisement
  from adafruit_ble.services.standard.hid import HIDService
  from adafruit_ble.services.standard.device_info import DeviceInfoService
  from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard
  from adafruit_hid.keyboard_layout_us import KeyboardLayoutUS
  from adafruit_hid.keycode import Keycode

  button_1 = DigitalInOut(board.D11)
  button_2 = DigitalInOut(board.D10)
  button_3 = DigitalInOut(board.D9)
  button_4 = DigitalInOut(board.D6)
  button_5 = DigitalInOut(board.D5)

  button_1.direction = Direction.INPUT
  button_2.direction = Direction.INPUT
  button_3.direction = Direction.INPUT
  button_4.direction = Direction.INPUT
  button_5.direction = Direction.INPUT

  hid = HIDService()

  device_info = DeviceInfoService(software_revision=adafruit_ble.__version__,
                                  manufacturer="Adafruit Industries")
  advertisement = ProvideServicesAdvertisement(hid)
  advertisement.appearance = 961
  scan_response = Advertisement()
  scan_response.complete_name = "CircuitPython HID"

  ble = adafruit_ble.BLERadio()
  if not ble.connected:
      print("advertising")
      ble.start_advertising(advertisement, scan_response)
  else:
      print("already connected")
      print(ble.connections)

  k = Keyboard(hid.devices)
  kl = KeyboardLayoutUS(k)
  while True:
      while not ble.connected:
          pass
      print("Start typing:")

      while ble.connected:
          if not button_1.value:  # pull up logic means button low when pressed
              k.send(Keycode.DOWN_ARROW)
              time.sleep(0.4)

          if not button_2.value:
              k.send(Keycode.LEFT_ARROW)
              time.sleep(0.4)

          if not button_3.value:
              k.send(Keycode.UP_ARROW)
              time.sleep(0.4)

          if not button_4.value:
              k.send(Keycode.RIGHT_ARROW)
              time.sleep(0.4)

          if not button_5.value:
              k.send(Keycode.ENTER)
              time.sleep(0.4)

      ble.start_advertising(advertisement)
```

Answer (score 0):

USB HID keyboards require you to release any keys that you press, otherwise the host will (usually) perform a "typomatic" repeat of the last key it saw pressed.

Try calling release_all() after each key press. More info is in the source code at:

https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/hid/en/latest/_modules/adafruit_hid/keyboard.html#Keyboard.release_all

Answer (score 0):

Aja,

Thanks for your response. The problem was that the sequence was starting without pressing any key. Finally (thanks to Dave) setting the pull property of each button to digitalio.Pull.UP did the trick.
However, I'll give a try with your solution because I think it will surely be useful later in my project.

Regards

Philippe